# My background is black but I want my images to show over the black

Tags: html, css

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

h1 {
    font: bold 20 px Tahoma;
}

h2 {
    font: bold 14px Tahoma;
}

header, section, footer, aside, nav, article, {
    display: block;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    background-color: black;
    color:white;
}

#bigwrapper {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 20px 0px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-flex; 1;
}

#topheader {
    background:white;

    padding: 20px;
    text-shadow: rgb(110, 110, 110) 3px 3px 5px;
```

Basically I have some images in my topheader, while the background of the webpage is black it causes the images to just show up plain black, how do I make it to where the images show through the black background?

If you need to see my main code, please let me know.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>About us</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="bigwrapper">
    <header id="topheader">
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <center><img width="200" height="200" class="irc_mi iGDtkhtShETk-pQOPx8XEepE" style="margin-top: 0px;" alt="" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/1/5/2/f/1219988685315274755checkered%20flag.svg.hi.png">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <img class="spotlight" aria-busy="true" aria-describedby="fbPhotosSnowliftCaption" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;" alt="" src="https://scontent-atl3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xla1/v/t1.0-9/12313702_922106124540079_548849285871043524_n.jpg?oh=562422204798663858ab12d90c64b7c8&amp;oe=5773C80B">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <img width="200" height="200" class="irc_mi iGDtkhtShETk-pQOPx8XEepE" style="margin-top: 0px;" alt="" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/k/M/F/0/t/p/finish-line-flag-pin-hi.png">
        <h1> Welcome to the About Us page for Exclusive Automotive!</h1>
    </header>
```

Comment: Please add some html code.

Comment: Can't reproduce. As you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1rb1tze4/) yourself, the images appear just fine. You probably have something else breaking your design.

Comment: Shouldn't "`-webkit-box-flex; 1;`" be "`-webkit-box-flex: 1;`" (colon after "webkit-box-flex" instead of semicolon)?

Answer (score 0):

You could set a white background for the images:

```
img {
 background: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `background` from `#topheader`, and you can try inverting images.

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

h1 {
    font: bold 20 px Tahoma;
}

h2 {
    font: bold 14px Tahoma;
}

header, section, footer, aside, nav, article, {
    display: block;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

#bigwrapper {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 20px 0px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-flex; 1;
}

#topheader {
    /* background: white; */

    padding: 20px;
    text-shadow: rgb(110, 110, 110) 3px 3px 5px;
}

.irc_mi {
    -webkit-filter: invert(1);
    filter: invert(1);
}
```

```html
<div id="bigwrapper">
<header id="topheader">
<br>
<br>
<br>
<center><img width="200" height="200" class="irc_mi iGDtkhtShETk-pQOPx8XEepE" style="margin-top: 0px;" alt="" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/1/5/2/f/1219988685315274755checkered%20flag.svg.hi.png">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<img class="spotlight" aria-busy="true" aria-describedby="fbPhotosSnowliftCaption" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;" alt="" src="https://scontent-atl3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xla1/v/t1.0-9/12313702_922106124540079_548849285871043524_n.jpg?oh=562422204798663858ab12d90c64b7c8&amp;oe=5773C80B">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<img width="200" height="200" class="irc_mi iGDtkhtShETk-pQOPx8XEepE" style="margin-top: 0px;" alt="" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/k/M/F/0/t/p/finish-line-flag-pin-hi.png">
<h1> Welcome to the About Us page for Exclusive Automotive!</h1>
```